# Are hit points non-fungible?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, hit-points

There are many effects in D&D 5e which reduce a target's maximum hit points. Take for example, the [Vampire's](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/vampire) bite which contains the following rider:

> The target's hit point maximum is reduced by an amount equal to the necrotic damage taken.

This phrasing is relatively easy to understand and is consistent with the rest of 5e's hit point definitions.

Now let's look at the [Sword of Wounding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/sword-of-wounding). Its description has interesting implications when you consider the first sentence:

> Hit points lost to this weapon's damage can be regained only through a short or long rest, rather than by regeneration, magic, or any other means.

The phrasing for this effect is very different from other similar effects such as the aforementioned Vampire's bite as it targets *specific hit points*. While this makes sense in concept and fantasy (the wounds inflicted by this sword are not easily healed), I find myself scratching my head when thinking about how this works in practice.

For example, let's say that a [Troll](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/troll) has lost all but 15 of its hit points to varied (nonmagical) sources of damage. When those 15 hit points are subsequently lost to a Fighter wielding a Sword of Wounding, can the Troll use its Regeneration to return to 10 HP? I can see two different scenarios here:

1. Option 1 (non-fungible hit points): its "first" 15 hit points have been lost and can't be regained. Because these can't be regained, no subsequent hit points can be regained and the Troll remains at 0 HP.
2. Option 2 (fungible hit points): the "un-healable" hit points effectively function as a maximum hit point reduction, and the Troll regenerates back to 10 HP. On subsequent turns, its total hit points cannot exceed more than [*its max hp* - 15].

Are there any official sources which indicate how this works? Specifically, I'm interested in understanding whether hit points are fungible (i.e. they can be regained independently from one another) or otherwise.

---

Some additional, opinion-based context: D&D is fundamentally a story-based game, so thematically, there's a lot of wiggle room for how this can be interpreted while remaining within the bounds of hit points as a concept. Option 1 fits with the idea that taking the last hit points constitutes the "killing blow". Option 2 fits with the idea of "death by a thousand cuts" (the other wounds can be healed to stave off death). The spirit of this question is basically asking whether the Sword of Wounding canonizes one of these interpretations, **and asks if there are other rules which provide more clarity around this**.

Comment: Related but adjacent: [What happens when you bring a creature down to 0 HP entirely by a "Sword of Wounding", but choose to deal nonlethal damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86371/56975)

Comment: Why do you assume that if "those" 15 points cannot be healed, other 10 cannot be either? Did you found anything in rules that demands recovering HP "in order"?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot I find this comment funny; aren't you basically restating the exact question that OP is asking?

Comment: @perennial I question the outcome of option 1 being correct. Question itself is quite interesting, because it can potentially have a difference. I cannot think about example right now, but interaction between rules like _these hitpoints disappear_ and _these hit points cannot be healed_ might be different, depending on answer to this question.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot I've added some context to the bottom that might give you a better idea of where this interpretation comes from. perrenial is correct that the question you've asked is essentially the spirit of my question: SoW's description lays the groundwork for implying the existence of non-fungible hit points. This question asks if there are other rules which support this. Feel free to add your own answer if you want to pose a frame-challenge! I'm interested in all interpretations.

Comment: Re: the title, fungible is not really the right word here; you seem to be interested in whether the "order" of hit each hit point is significant (it is not). They are _all_ still hitpoints... there is no 'funging' going on.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### There are no hidden rules. HP are fungible.

Given the possible interpretations, in the absence of any text that *forces* us to pick the more complex interpretation, we should default to the simpler reading. We should not go out of our way to invent additional assumptions which the rules do not require in order to be coherent. (You may be familiar with this concept as "Occam's Razor".)

There are no rules that state or imply that HP are non-fungible. That is to say, all hit points are identical and interchangeable; there isn't an order to them. Your "last" HP isn't special or different from the others. We should not accept your Option #1 unless there is some specific rules text that supports or requires it, and since that text just doesn't exist, we're left to default to Option #2.

HP lost to a Wound can't be healed, but any HP lost in other ways can be, so the Sword of Wounding's damage can't "lock off" the rest of your HP. If your last HP was lost to a Wound, you can still heal all the other HP you have that weren't caused by Wounds, whether that healing comes from troll regeneration or a *cure* spell.

So yes, Sword of Wounding damage works kind of like reducing maximum hit points (though it does not, technically speaking, actually change your max HP). Why is it worded differently from the Vampire's ability? We can't say. But we can be aware that different books (and often different sections in the same book) are written by different authors, edited by different editors, and often not cross-checked to see if they're using consistent language.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134542/discussion-on-answer-by-darth-pseudonym-are-hit-points-non-fungible).

Comment: (not continuing previous discussion, suggesting an improvement) If I remember the rules correctly bloodied is triggered by reaching a certain % of maximum HP. My suspicion is the language is written that way so the sword of wounding would still trigger that at the normal time. (The creature still sees that it's wounded and begins fighting more desperately). On the other hand a vampire bite reducing the max HP likely wouldn't trigger the same response of seeing one's self becoming badly wounded. If I am not totally mistaken mentioning this reaction might add value here.

Comment: @Vality "Bloodied" is a 4e mechanic that doesn't exist in 5e.  I can't swear there isn't an ability *somewhere* in the game that activates when a creature has less than half their maximum hit points, but it's not common or standardized, so it's unlikely the Sword of Wounding is designed specifically around such a mechanic.

Answer (score 56):

### Option 2

This is what the description of the sword says: “Hit points lost to this weapon's damage can be regained only …”. It does not affect hit points lost in other ways, they can be healed normally. In effect, it creates a separate class of hit points that are, if you like, non-fungible with normal hit points.

Note that this is *different* from lowering the hit point maximum. A lower maximum makes the character more susceptible to death from massive damage; hit points lost to the sword don’t do this.

Comment: While I recognize that this is the "obvious" answer (and I appreciate the clarification about massive damage), this doesn't answer my question. This answer only really restates the description of the weapon but it doesn't provide a qualified explanation of what would happen in the scenario I described. Specifically, is the "killing blow" on a monster special in any way that would interact with the SoW's special effect?

Comment: @Andrendire It's going to be difficult to find any official sources saying that a specific mechanic that doesn't exist does in fact not exist.  I don't think the ability to read the SoW's description a certain way is ultimately a basis to make further conclusions beyond "precision+concision is hard".

Comment: You just state the answer without backing it up in any way. Would love to see some kind of logic or quotes to back your assertions up.

Comment: @MatthewRead I fully recognize this, and in fact your statement would be a good foundation for its own answer. The point stands however, that from the perspective of a Q&A, stating the description of SoW does not answer the root question concerning hit point fungibility. It's certainly relevant to the question as I have posed it, but I can't accept it as a complete answer.

Comment: Option 2 makes more sense from a story telling perspective: The afore mentioned Troll has 84 HP. It takes 6 damage from a crossbow. Then it takes 10 damage from SOW. Of its two different wounds, only one can be regenerated — it can regenerate 6 damage. Chill Touch's explicit description is the mechanic you're thinking in a NFT way: "...it can't regain hit points..."

Answer (score 16):

### It doesn't matter

The existing answers do a good job of showing that hit points are fungible (a position I agree with). I'd like to take a different approach: **for the sake of argument, I'll assume that hit points are *non*-fungible** and see if that makes any difference.

Bob is a level 1 bard with 14 Con, thus he has 10 hit points. Throughout the adventuring day, **Bob takes the following damage** (in order):

1. A single dart of *magic missile* for 2 force damage.
2. A hit from a *sword of wounding* for 3 piercing damage.
3. Damage from a wound from a *sword of wounding* for 1 necrotic damage.
4. A dagger hit for 3 piercing damage.

Bob's (presumably) non-fungible hit points now look like this **(repetition intentional)**:

- 1 hit point flagged as lost to *magic missile* force damage.
- 1 hit point flagged as lost to *magic missile* force damage.
- 1 hit point flagged as lost from *sword of wounding* piercing damage.
- 1 hit point flagged as lost from *sword of wounding* piercing damage.
- 1 hit point flagged as lost from *sword of wounding* piercing damage.
- 1 hit point flagged as lost from *sword of wounding* necrotic damage.
- 1 hit point flagged as lost from a dagger's piercing damage.
- 1 hit point flagged as lost from a dagger's piercing damage.
- 1 hit point flagged as lost from a dagger's piercing damage.
- 1 hit point flagged as not lost.

**Bob then casts *healing word*** (1d4+3) on himself, getting an unlucky roll of 4. Per *healing word*, **Bob regains 4 hit points**. He looks at his selection of non-fungible hit points and selects the two *magic missile* flagged hit points and two of the dagger damage flagged hit points.

Bob's non-fungible hit points now look like this:

- 1 hit point flagged as not lost.
- 1 hit point flagged as not lost.
- 1 hit point flagged as lost from *sword of wounding* piercing damage.
- 1 hit point flagged as lost from *sword of wounding* piercing damage.
- 1 hit point flagged as lost from *sword of wounding* piercing damage.
- 1 hit point flagged as lost from *sword of wounding* necrotic damage.
- 1 hit point flagged as not lost.
- 1 hit point flagged as lost from a dagger's piercing damage.
- 1 hit point flagged as not lost.
- 1 hit point flagged as not lost.

*Healing word* doesn't say to regain the most recent N hit points lost. **Spells do only what they say they do, so Bob can choose any four (non-*sword of wounding*) hit points to regain.**<sup>+</sup> This is true for every method of regaining hit points. When asked what his current hit points are, Bob counts each one individually and says "five" - the same result he would get with fungible hit points.

---

<sup>+</sup> If an argument is made that hit points are non-fungible *and* ordered, then healing spells (as written) *still* allow you to regain arbitrary hit points in any order. This leads to the absurd situation where *healing word* can heal any creature to full by specifically targeting their "top-most" hit point.

Comment: I don't see why we can't assume that hp is LIFO? That feels like the most natural since it's how pretty much any video game or tabletop game does it. Eg in minecraft If your hp is ♥♥♥ and you take 2 damage it becomes ♥♡♡, then if you are healed by 1 point it becomes ♥♥♡. From a modern perspective that's how fungible hp would (does?) work in general.

Comment: That's just a graphical representation. Most video games will just do math on the single integer that is your health, then display the resulting integer in a nice way. They could just as easily display ♥♡♥.

Comment: They could, but they don't. Universally HP is represented as non-fungible LIFO, this is something that has become the norm. To be clear; I think your answer is overall good, but I just think that assumption is quite weak considering how pervasive it is in reality.

Comment: "LIFO? That feels like the most natural since it's how pretty much any video game or tabletop game does it." I have never seen HP as LIFO in any gaming system I have played (that's *mostly* 1e, 2e, 3.xe, and 5e D&D but some others also). I think the LIFO assumption is a very poor one. Red Orca, I **really** like your example with healing spells: It makes yours the strongest answer to my mind.

Comment: @Non-humanPerson I've been playing video games for over 30 years and I never thought of life meters as anything more than a gauge displaying a level.  By your logic you *would* see ♥♡♥ in games if that were the case.  In fact if games do have special HP buckets and rules regarding them they are displayed separately.   I've played games where items give you 'temporary' hp that are lost first before affecting your real hp for instance.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question as stated. Non-fungible does *not* imply ordered.

Comment: @Lexible Understandable, if you haven't played a game that represents hp with a LIFO queue then I can see why you'd be resistant to the idea.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat I am not sure why you'd see that, clearly that's not LIFO!

Comment: @Non-humanPerson Resistant in the context specifically of **Dungeons & Dragons**. :)

Comment: @Lexible lol ^^

Answer (score 4):

### Hit points are fungible

Unfortunately a direct quote saying "hit points are a pool" doesn't exist. However, we do have evidence that the designers intend hit points to be fungible - look at [this example about tracking hit points from the DMG Chapter 8](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#TrackingMonsterHitPoints):

> For example, in a combat encounter with three ogres, you could use
> three identical ogre miniatures tagged with stickers marked A, B, and
> C, respectively. To track the ogres’ hit points, you can sort them by
> letter, then subtract damage from their hit points as they take it.
> Your records might look something like this after a few rounds of
> combat:
>
> Ogre A: <strike>59</strike> <strike>53</strike> <strike>45</strike> <strike>24</strike> <strike>14</strike> <strike>9</strike> dead
>
> Ogre B: <strike>59</strike> <strike>51</strike> 30
>
> Ogre C: 59

The designers suggest tracking only the total number of hit points, not the hit points themselves. While the rest of the rules could be read coherently with the assumption that hit points are non-fungible, this example would make little sense in that framework.

Comment: This is a good point and likely the closest we can get to official confirmation. I think also (as pointed out by Red Orca) the fact that other abilities specify non-specific damage/healing also supports the idea that hit points are fungible *at least in the general case*.

Answer (score -2):

Hit points that cannot be recovered ... lower the maximum HP you can reach.

Treating this as a different exception to how HP works adds complication to the game with very little benefit here.

All forms of lowering your HP maximum either implicitly or explicitly explain how the HP maximum can be recovered.  This one says healing via HD in a short rest, or a long rest, recovers it.  The vampire states the reduction lasts until a long rest.

You should be relatively leery about treating 5e rules as if they where using keywords.  There are a few spots where you have to do this (melee weapon attack is the worst one; but they include bonus action/action and a few others), but outside of those try to treat it as natural language, and err on the side of simplicity.

The failure to say the word "maximum" should not be taken as strong evidence that this is a distinct kind of effect than ones that do say "maximum".  It behaves just like a "reduced HP maximum" effect, the game is simpler if it is a "reduced HP maximum" effect, and there aren't any serious balance concerns if you treat it like "reduced HP maximum" effects.  So do it.

This means that Greater Restoration would also let you heal these wounds (at the cost of some diamond dust and a 5th level slot).

Comment: I agree with most of your answer, but like you say the description should be treated as natural language -- and in natural language, it is extremely clear that only rests can restore the HP.  It's not valid to say a Greater Restoration could be used just because it could be used with reduced HP max effects that _don't_ have such a restriction.

Comment: @MatthewRead yes, if you assume "maximum" is a keyword, you are right.  I am not treating it as a keyword; I am treating it as a description.  An effect which lowers the maximum HP you can heal to is an effect that lowers your maximum HP.  Vampire bite does not say "or greater restoration".  And balance wise, burning a 5th level slot, diamonds and an action is a reasonable extra cost.