# Are there any more ways to regain spent hit dice?

Tags: dnd-5e, hit-dice, resource-consumption

I am aware of the rules surrounding long rests and hit dice. What I am interested in here is whether there is any way apart from long resting to regain any number of hit dice?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### No

Aside from "do what you want" abilities like *Wish*-ing to recover your hit dice (in whatever in-character phrasing you desire), the answer is No. This appears to be an intentional design decision, such that long rests are *the* limiting factor on healing. To achieve this, in general, all sources of healing either:

1. Use spell slots (only recovered in unbounded sense by long rests for all but warlocks), or
2. Spend hit dice (also recovered by long rests)
3. Have a recharge cycle directly tied to long rests (e.g. Paladin's *Lay on Hands*, Celestial Warlock's *Healing Light*) or, for magic items which generally aren't phrased in terms of long rests, the day cycle (which isn't all that different from per-long-rest in most cases)
4. Expend finite resources (e.g. money/magic items) and therefore run out eventually (not technically long rest bounded, but bounded by money, which the game assumes is fairly finite).

In practice, stuff like the [Coffeelock](https://www.geeknative.com/64235/dungeons-and-dragons-what-is-a-coffeelock/) exists, and certain class & feat combinations could use exploits like that to produce a meaningful amount of spell-based healing limited only by short rests, not long rests, but hit dice, to my knowledge, have no exploits that allow you to recover them without a long rest.

Comment: Just to complete the list, Paladin's healing is also bounded by long rests

Comment: @biziclop: Yep. Same goes for the Celestial Warlock's *Healing Light* pool of dice healing. Even when a class provides a non-spell source of healing, it either: 1) Requires you to spend hit dice (possibly amplified by the power, as in the Bard's *Song of Rest*), or 2) Recharges on a per-long-rest basis. The answer as written wasn't as clear about that as it should have been, so I've added a third item addressing that.

Comment: As far as "the limiting factor on healing" is concerned, it's worth mentioning that there are non-exploit exceptions to this, such as the Way of Mercy Monk using Martial Arts dice (which recover on a short rest) to heal, or the Life Domain Cleric's Channel Divinity feature providing healing while recharging on a short rest - and of course Celestial Warlocks can cast Cure Wounds with their recharged-on-short-rest spell slots. It's a good general rule, but not a hard rule.

Comment: The point of Coffeelock is banking up large amount of resources to have it all with no rests.  A normal Celestial Warlock can cast Cure Wounds with spell slots that recover on a short rest, as you mentioned in point 1.  (But unlike divine soul sorcs, they don't get the full cleric list, so they can't learn efficient group heals like Prayer of Healing.  For that, you'd need to multi-class, e.g. celestial / divine-soul sorlock could even work.)

Comment: There are some ways other than multi-classing for a warlock to learn 1st-level healing spells like Cure Wounds (e.g. Mark of Healing halfling sub-race from Eberron, or the Witherbloom Student background from Strixhaven), but RAW, the Magic Initiate feat does *not* let you use spell slots to cast the spell you learn.  However, more recent feats (Artificer Initiate, Gift of the Metallic Dragon, and Strixhaven Initiate) *do* allow using your own spell slots.  The latter two allow your choice of casting stat.

Comment: A Mark of Healing Halfling warlock can learn Prayer of Healing (2nd) or Aura of Vitality (3rd) and cast that with their short-rest spell slots for efficient out-of-combat healing.  Strixhaven's Quandrix Student background also adds Aura of Vitality to your spell list.  So yeah, I guess you could consider that an exploit similar to Coffeelock (healing directly with your short-rest slots instead of manufacturing sorc slots from them), especially in a "gritty realism" campaign where long rests are hard to come by so you'd want to do this regularly.

Comment: Anyway yeah, IDK another way to recover spent hit dice either.  Bard Song of Rest and the Chef feat can make each hit die heal for more, especially if you take multiple short rests to spend one at a time (e.g. in gritty realism), but that's still limited.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yeah, it's inevitable that some slight power creep in violation of the original intent occurs over time (see: 4E, and their carefully limited single interrupt/reaction per round to keep off-turn actions under control, and how, as 4E wore on, they kept ignoring that and making a ton of "free action that happens to interrupt"-type powers until, at high levels, every round was just non-stop "free interrupt/reactions" if the characters were well optimized for action economy). Way of Mercy monk and Celestial Warlock are good examples of certain general rules being violated later on.

Comment: I will say that I only barely consider the Celestial Warlock a violation of this general rule. Their slots are *so* limited (just two per short-rest until tenth level, even if the slots scale up), that for all practical purposes, barring Coffeelock cheese, they'd have to short rest for the length of a long rest to cast enough healing for it to matter; they're not meaningfully more effective as healers than another full caster with only daily slots, but a *lot* more of them.

Comment: Yup, agreed, pure Celestial Warlock isn't a significant amount of per-short-rest out-of-combat healing.  You need access to something like Prayer of Healing or Aura of Vitality for those two warlock slots to become meaningful beyond level 2 or 3, probably even in gritty realism.  Taking feats or background options, or multi-classing, to get those on a warlock would definitely be something you did on purpose.

Comment: One [healing method](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/92896/23547) is to repeatedly damage someone unconscious / stabilize them (such as with _spare the dying_) until they eventually roll a 20N on their death save and gain 1hp.  This is 'unlimited' in that it expends no slots or resources other than time and actions and results in healing.  However, in practice it is limited because it can only take someone from 0hp to 1hp.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be mentioned yet, but Healer's Kit with the Healer feat is bounded by the target of the healing needing to rest in between applications.

Comment: @RisingZan: As well as being bounded by resource costs, since the kits aren't free (admittedly, not particularly high resource costs).

Comment: @ShadowRanger  Even at level 1, the 5gp cost is pretty minimal. Beyond that it should be inconsequential, unless you're running some sort of grimdark setting with limited resources or treasure.  With 10 uses per kit, it's 1% of the cost of an equivalent amount of healing potions, and with more average healing per usage (2d4+2 = 7 vs 1d6+4+HD = 8.5 on a level 1 target).  Also, less encumbrance than healing potions (10 uses = weight of 6 potions).  The "real" cost is the possible loss of another feat or stat increase.

Answer (score 9):

### Variant Rules and Homebrew

As [Shadow Ranger's excellent answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/208022/48759) states, the simple answer is **no**. This is likely an intentional design decision to limit the availability of healing without a long rest. However, depending on your game and if your table is open to it there can be other options.

#### Optional Rule: Healing Surges

Chapter 9 of the DMG contains a number of variant / optional rules that might suit your group. One of these options, Healing Surges, changes how Hit Dice are regained:

> #### Healing Surges
>
> This optional rule allows characters to heal up in the thick of combat and works well for parties that feature few or no characters with healing magic, or for campaigns in which magical healing is rare.
> [...]
>
> Under this optional rule, a character regains all spent Hit Dice at the end of a long rest. With a short rest, a character regains Hit Dice equal to his or her level divided by four (minimum of one die).

### Homebrew Rule: Comfy Beds

In my current campaign we are utilising another of the variant rules, Gritty Realism:

> This variant uses a short reset of 8 hours and a long rest of 7 days.

Using this rules massively increases the importance of Hit Dice and short rest healing. Particularly in my exploration based campaign where places to safely rest for 7 days are few and far between. Therefore to help the party manage healing and reduce pressure on the Cleric's spell slots I introduced the following homebrew rule:

> #### Comfy Beds
>
> When completing a short rest, if a character is sleeping in a comfortable bed (such as may be purchased in a nice tavern or home rather than rough camp bed) they regain one hit dice. This hit dice may be spent to recover hit points during the same rest as it was earned.

This house rule encourages the party to engage with the environment, paying for inn stays and making allies rather than camping outside of towns. So far the feedback from my players has been highly positive, particularly from the Cleric (frees up spell slots for more interesting things) and the fighter (party tank needs the most healing).

Comment: Not so sure simple answer is no with examples of optional DMG rules provided in this answer. Sure looks like a yes to me. Bounty incoming.

Comment: @NautArch-is-skeptical-about-SE Depends if OP is in a game that would allow optional rules. Even then these aren't additional ways to gain hit dice as they involve modifying the existing way of gaining them.